# IBM Worklight 6.0: "can not access development servlets in production mode"

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a Worklight application which has Cookie-based Push Notification.

This application works for Android devices and I have tested it on Worklight Developer Edition by using the `PushBackendEmulator.jar` as given below and it works fine.

```
 java –jar PushBackendEmulator.jar <userId> <notificationText> <context
 root> <serverPort>
```

The same application I had deployed in Production environment. Android devices are able to subscribe and unsunscribe, I can able to see number devices subscribed in Push Notifications tab of Worklight Console.

Now the problem is, if I trigger a notification to an android device by using the above code I am getting the following error.

> SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[DevRootServlet]:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Can not access development servlets in
>   production mode

Comment: You need to really explain what do you mean by "production" as well as what is the backend you are using in your production environment for storing and using push notifications... It's not as simple matter of "just sending a message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PushBackendEmulator.jar` that is provided as part of the [Push Notifications sample project](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced) is just that - an emulator and was not designed to work anywhere other than the development environment. It should not and cannot be used in a production environment.

If you want to test push notifications in your production environment then I suggest that you will implement an actual, real backend and solution for sending push notifications.

1. [See this blog post about possible push notifications architectures](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_push_notification_possible_architectures?lang=en)
2. [Push Notifications in IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_push_notification.html)

For example, you can use a JMS adapter in your Worklight project as a means of controlling notification **polling**.

To read more about JMS (notification polling, if this is what you want in your app):

- [What is JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service)
- [Using JMS adapters training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_05_JMS_adapter_-_Communicating_with_JMS.pdf)
- [JSM adapters in the IBM Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jms_adapters.html)
- [JMS adapter questions in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D%20jms%20is:question)

Comment: The link "Push Notifications in IBM Worklight Information Center" returns "Topic not found". I would go with the second option of Push Notification Implementation. I have used the following URL to trigger 'http://localhost:9080/worklight/invoke?adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=["0e1c2421-8e5d-4ebe-b8d5-c80727bc085b","newtext"]'. But I am getting this as result "/*-secure-{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"75edfkvs529m75pgmj2fm9n5o6"}}}*/".

Comment: The Information Center may be down on Sundays, try again later or tomorrow. Note you are starting to mix questions and it will be difficult to understand what the original issue was in this question. Please don't mix questions. I have answered your original question.

Comment: As for the current issue you are facing, see if the following helps. If it won't help, open a new question and explain your problem in DETAIL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766776/ibm-worklight-6-0-wl-antixsrfrealm-error-after-deploying-adapter-to-worklight